# How to replace an '_' in a list with a letter corresponding to an earlier list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm making a hangman game for my school project, and have a problem. I can't get a list to update in specific places with the same '_ ' comparing to a previous list of the word that was selected.

The code so far:

```
root = Tk()

word_list = ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANNANA"]

word = word_list [random.randrange(-1,3)]

hidden_word = ["_ "] * len(word)
print (hidden_word)    #Placeholder/testing#

#Functions
def click_1 (text):
    print (text)       #Placeholder#


#Frames
hangman_frame = Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0)
letter_frame = Frame(root).grid(row=1, column=0)



#Buttons
r = c = 0
for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    Button(letter_frame, text=letter, command=functools.partial(click_1, letter)).grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=W)
    c += 1
    if c > 12:
        c = 0
        r += 1
```

thanks for any help you can give - I am new to python, so please forgive if this seems stupid!

Comment: can you show that whats the problem exactly ? whats the expected out put ?

Comment: @Kasra    _ _ _ _...(etc.) changing to A _ ...(etc.). Those underscores are from the list made: word_list = ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANNANA"]

word = word_list [random.randrange(-1,3)]

hidden_word = ["_ "] * len(word)

Comment: Where are you actually trying to do this?

Comment: @Reut Sharabani      word_list = ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANNANA"]

word = word_list [random.randrange(-1,3)]

hidden_word = ["_ "] * len(word)                                          Thanks for any help!

Comment: @18166 please add your explanation to question !

Comment: Could you please explain what specifically is or is not happening? Just telling us that the code isn't working is not really sufficient.

Comment: @18166 , you still have some coding to go, but I added an answer detailing how to do it once you know what the user already guessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this function instead of continually hidding the word, with this you can send the letters already guessed as a second parameter :

```
def hide_word(word, letters=[]):
    letters = map(str.lower, letters)
    word = word.lower()
    print ''.join((letter if letter in letters else '_ ' for letter in word))

hide_word('hiddenword', ['i','d','n']) #_ idd_ n_ _ _ d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one problem, what is the [idn] for? It's not defined and I can't find anything about it on the internet? Misspell? No worries if it is, just asking.

Comment: @markcial - you changing the case of the word, you could avoid it if you only convert the letter when testing if it's in the letters :)

Comment: yes, or you can do a regular expression case insensitive match too, anyways my hint was to use a function for a more dynamic response and not a plain word

Comment: @markcial this doesn't fully solve my problem, as the _ _ _ gets replaced, and the letter that pops up is a 'Z' instead of anything else. Looks a lot neater now though! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I *hate* regular expressions :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet that should allow you to better understand what to do:

```
def reveal(word, letters):
    return ''.join([w if w.lower() in letters.lower() else "_" for w in word])
print reveal("Banana", "ba")
```

Output:

> Ba_a_a

What happens is you send two strings to the `reveal` function, one is the word to be guessed, one is the letters already guessed. A new string is then composed replacing all letters not guessed with a place-holder '_'.